# Fatal Exception in Marketing Cloud SDK (Android) - RejectedExecutionException

Tags: android, sfdcmobilesdk-android, mobilepush-android, salesforce-sdk-android

We are using Salesforce SDK 8.0.4. In the recent release, we have RejectedExecutionException.

I am not sure if it is related but we started reconfiguring Salesforce when the user changes their Tracking Consent.

```
Fatal Exception: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task com.salesforce.marketingcloud.registration.e$c@e7ce5b7 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@bb5c124[Shutting down, pool size = 1, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 1, completed tasks = 9]
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2086)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:848)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1394)
   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$DelegatedExecutorService.execute(Executors.java:630)
   at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.registration.e.a(e.java:35)
   at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.registration.d.a(d.java:52)
   at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.http.c$b.a(c.java:6)
   at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.internal.g.run(g.java:17)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
```

What would cause crash and how can we prevent it happening?

Comment: Open a support case.

Comment: Are you using any of these methods? https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/analytics/analytics.html#integration-methods

Comment: We use `requestSdk`, `sdk.mp`. We dont use any of the tracking method.

Comment: Do you have PI Analytics enabled?  If so, disable it.  There are 2 toggles in the SDK's configuration.  PI is only used with those tracking methods.

Comment: setPiAnalyticsEnabled is enabled. I dont think we use it at all. I will check for tracking calls and disable it.

Comment: I have opened a bug ticket to address your scenario: pi enabled and reconfiguring the SDK, obviously uncommon as you're our first report of this.  If you're not using `trackCart`, `trackPageView`, or `trackCartContents` you can disable PI without affecting anything.

Comment: Thank you. we are about to do a release without Pi.

Comment: Please follow up here :)

Comment: We reduced the amount of Salesforce SDK configuration by using debounce. And we removed setPiAnalyticsEnabled(true) call. But we still have crashes. Number of crashes is dropped significantly but crash is still happening.

Comment: Open a support case.

Answer (score 1):

Version 8.0.5 has been released and addresses this issue.

UPDATE 20221214 -- If you are using the legacy v7.x SDK natively, or as a result of using the Cordova or React plugins, a fix has been back-ported, and v7.4.4 of the SDK has been released to address this issue.